# Looking for OpenSC compatibile token

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, smartcard

I am currently proud user of `Feitan ePass2003` with `OpenSC`, however it is not 100% reliable on Windows, on Linux it's just perfect.

Anyway I started to looking and I have two candidates **eToken Pro 64K** by SafeNet and **AESKey** by Athena, they are both supported by `OpenSC`, but I could not find any reseller in Central Europe, it actually looks like they are not more on market.

So, could you recommend me any other OpenSC+CCID complain token which is available and is able to handle at least `2048b + sha1/sha256`?
Do you know for example any CCID complain token with `CardOS`, as `CardOS` is generally supported by `OpenSC`?